# Regex to find first capital letter occurrence in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, .net-2.0

I want to find the index of first capital letter occurrence in a string.

E.g. -

```
String x = "soHaM";
```

Index should return 2 for this string. The regex should ignore all other capital letters after the first one is found. If there are no capital letters found then it should return 0. Please help.

Comment: Why are you using Regex?

Comment: Indeed!  Why not just use a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all you need is the regex <strike>`A-Z`</strike> `\p{Lu}`:

```
public static class Find
{
  // Apparently the regex below works for non-ASCII uppercase
  // characters (so, better than A-Z).
  static readonly Regex CapitalLetter = new Regex(@"\p{Lu}");

  public static int FirstCapitalLetter(string input)
  {
    Match match = CapitalLetter.Match(input);

    // I would go with -1 here, personally.
    return match.Success ? match.Index : 0;
  }
}
```

Did you try this?

Comment: Looks good. Note that if you use 0 as a return value that signals no capital you cannot differentiate between the case where the first letter is a capital and if there is no capital

Comment: @buckley: I agree that it seems strange.

Comment: @buckley `\p{Lu}` would get uppercase characters, but the `\p{Z}` would match spaces and line/paragraph separators and the `\p{P}` would match punctuation. OP just wanted capital letters.

Comment: So to work *correctly* (not just "happen to work with a subset of English words"), this should be `new Regex("\\p{Lu}")`, not `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Yes wrong copy paste of me. It is \p{Lu} or @"\p{Lu}" if you prefer verbatim strings

Comment: Are there really performance issue as oppose to using a for loop? I thought regex would be faster.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta, the Regex is just going to loop and call `Char.IsUpper` (or one of its moral equivalents). It can't possibly be *faster* than the loop, and would likely be at least a little bit slower. At best it might be quicker and easier to write, or more readable, or more maintainable. (Though with something this simple, possibly none of the above.)

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, a LINQ solution:

```
string x = "soHaM";
var index = from ch in x.ToArray()
            where Char.IsUpper(ch)
            select x.IndexOf(ch);
```

This returns `IEnumerable<Int32>`. If you want the index of the first upper case character, simply call `index.First()` or retrieve only the first instance in the LINQ:

```
string x = "soHaM";
var index = (from ch in x.ToArray()
            where Char.IsUpper(ch)
            select x.IndexOf(ch)).First();
```

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, here is another LINQ method (possibly more performant than my initial suggestion):

```
string x = "soHaM";
x.Select((c, index) => new { Char = c, Index = index }).First(c => Char.IsUpper(c.Char)).Index;
```

Comment: Faster: `x.Select((c, index) => new { Char = c, Index = index }).First(c => Char.IsUpper(c.Char)).Index;`

Comment: @JamesHill Sorry James, am stuck to version 2.0.

Comment: Calling `.First()` will throw an exception if there are no upper-case characters.  This can be handled, or you can instead use `.FirstOrDefault`, which will return `0` if there are no upper-case characters.  If you're using this LINQ query to trim the non-Uppercase characters off the beginning of the string, then using `.FirstOrDefault()` with the query will return the whole string untouched if there are no upper-case characters (in the case of `x.Substring(index)`).

Answer (score 4):

No need for `Regex`:

```
int firstUpper = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    if(Char.IsUpper(x[i]))
    {
        firstUpper = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isupper.aspx

For the sake of completeness, here's my LINQ approach(although it's not the right tool here even if OP could use it):

```
int firstUpperCharIndex = -1;
var upperChars = x.Select((c, index) => new { Char = c, Index = index })
                  .Where(c => Char.IsUpper(c.Char));
if(upperChars.Any())
    firstUpperCharIndex = upperChars.First().Index;
```

Answer (score 3):

First your logic fails, if the method returns 0 in your case it would mean the first char in that list was in upperCase, so I would recomend that -1 meens not found, or throw a exception.

Anyway just use regular expressions becasue you can is not always the best choise, plus they are pretty slow and hard to read in general, making yoru code much harder to work with.

Anyway here is my contribution

```
    public static int FindFirstUpper(string text)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            if (Char.IsUpper(text[i]))
                return i;

        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using loop

```
 int i = 0;
 for(i = 0; i < mystring.Length; i++)
 {
   if(Char.IsUpper(mystring, i))
    break;
 }
```

i is the value u should be looking at;

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

string word = "soHaMH";
var capChars = word.Where(c => char.IsUpper(c)).Select(c => c);
char capChar = capChars.FirstOrDefault();
int index = word.IndexOf(capChar);
```

Using C#:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string word = "soHaMH";
Match match= Regex.Match(word, "[A-Z]");
index = word.IndexOf(match.ToString());
```

Comment: Can someone please explain the `.Select(c => c)` part to me please